# How to detect scroll in a widget without using ListView or ScrollView?

Tags: flutter

I want to detect scroll in a widget but I am not using anything like `ListView` or `GridView`. I tried using `GestureDetector` like this:

```
void _verticalDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    started = details.localPosition;
  }

void _verticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
   final updatedPosition = details.localPosition;
    double difference = started.dy-updatedPosition.dy;
    //use difference in my code
  }
```

But for some reason its too rapid and gives very high values.
I tried using `Scrollable` widget but it doesn't update offset if `Viewport` builder isn't taking more space than available. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at a widget called ScrollNotification.

hope it works!

Comment: `ScrollNotification` notifies about scrolls in `Scrollable` widgets down the tree. Not useful for me.